# variable w/ spaces + ssh

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

EDIT:

It appears my primary issue is dealing with 'word' being empty on the remote host through every iteration of the FOR loop. The COLORS variable looks ok when I echo it, it shows all four colors.

I have a bash script with a FOR loop called via ssh like this:

```
ssh user@host02 <<EOF

COLORS=RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE

for word in $COLORS; do
 echo $word
done

exit
EOF
```

My output looks like this however:

```
ORANGE
ORANGE
ORANGE
ORANGE
```

The FOR loop identifies 4 space delmited args in the COLORS variable since it loops through and echos 4 times it owuld seem, but it only displays the last arg, ORANGE. What can I change so that each args is echoed?

Comment: What about changing `COLORS=RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE` to `COLORS="RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE"`?

Comment: that didn't seem to work, I get this error:  "echo ORANGE: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 problems:

1. Put quotes around variable assignment:
   `COLORS="RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE"`
2. Escape the `$` when using in HEREDOC.

Below code works:

```
ssh user@host02 <<EOF

COLORS="RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE"

for word in \$COLORS; do
 echo \$word
done

EOF
```

I also removed the un-necessary exit statement from it.

Comment: doesn't work for me, the variables aren't declared in the script. They're set in a properties file thats being injected into a build. The script/variable works fine when run without ssh, but inside it's causing problems.

Comment: Ok... my answer was based on whatever input script you gave :-) Unless you give the "properties file mechanism" you are using, I will not be able to update the answer...

Comment: My solution was changing the variable name in the FOR loop in conjunction with escaping the $. In using 'word' it looked like ORANGE was still saved there from the first iteration on my local host01, when I changed to 'arg' and then escaped the $ inside the ssh session it worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: I am curious, why you had to change the variable name from `word` to `arg`... Does your `.bashrc` overwrites `word`?

Comment: Im not sure, but it looked like 'word' had ORANGE stored in it from the previous iteration maybe, I don't know. The fact it recognized there were four space delmited args in variable COLOR mad me think COLOR wasn't the problem, maybe word was. So when I changed the variable to 'arg' it then output nothing instead of ORANGE, which then lead me to believe that the $ needed to be escaped because it was being substituted prior to use, which fixed that part. It may be coincedental with changing the var, but it works now so I'll just leave it as is.

Answer (score 4):

You need to protect the `$COLORS` and `$word` variables in your here-doc from expansion. They are being expanded on your local system before being sent to the remote system, and your local environment currently contains the equivalent of `COLORS="RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE"` and `word=ORANGE`, probably because you tested your little scriptlet locally before trying to run it remotely.

There are a couple ways to accomplish what you need. Probably the cleanest is this:

```
ssh user@host02 <<'EOF'
....
EOF
```

Note the single quotes around `EOF` on the introductory line. Alternatively, you can keep the here-doc specification as is, and escape the `$` signs in your script:

```
ssh user@host02 <<EOF
....
for word in \$COLORS; do
  echo \$word
done
EOF
```

This will protect only the specific variables you escape from local expansion, and is useful in cases where there are some variables you do want expanded locally, while others you want to expand on the remote end.

Answer (score 0):

put "" around the colors
cause at this point i think it sees that the color variable = orange. That s my guess because the for loop is good.

Comment: the variable or the values?

Comment: COLORS="RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE"

Answer (score 0):

Quoted [here documents](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) work:

```
ssh host <<'EOF'
COLORS='RED GREEN WHITE ORANGE'
for word in $COLORS; do
    echo "$word"
done
EOF
```

Some notes:

- You don't need `exit`. From `man ssh`:

  > The session terminates when the command or shell on the remote machine exits and all X11 and TCP connections have been closed.
- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting)